# Discord.py: Delay a channel delete - asyncio.sleep()

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have written a Discordbot in Python that for Voicechannel automatically also creates an associated Textchannel. However, if the bot crashes and stops running, the existing text channels are not deleted. So if a user enters voicechannel A, he doesn't get any rights for textchannel A anymore.

My preliminary idea would be, as soon as I restart the bot, it searches for the existing textchannels. Writes a message in it and deletes it after a minute. I have also implemented this, only the deletion after one minute does not want to work as I thought it would.

For the delay I use `asyncio.sleep(60)`. Without the delay it picks the channel IDs and writes to the channels one after the other. With delay it writes to the first channel, waits a minute and then writes to the next channel.

But I want it to write to all channels at once and then delete the text channels after one minute.

```
async def on_ready():

     #Bot Crash - Old Textchannel search
     for text_channel in guild.text_channels:
        if 'text' in text_channel.name:
           old_channels = text_channel
           await bot.get_channel(old_channels.id).send(embed=old_channel_embed(bot.user.avatar_url, old_channels.id))
           print(old_channels.id)

           await asyncio.sleep(60)
           await text_channel.delete()
```

Thanks & Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching the problem in the wrong way.

Your for loop is currently iterating over the channels of the guild. It then checks whether the channel should be deleted, sends an embed and waits for 60 seconds. Once that is done, it goes to the next channel.

Change your code structure. Send the embed to all the channels in one loop that doesn't block, then sleep for the 60 seconds **outside the loop**, followed by a loop that actually handles the deletion.

Comment: Ah okay. That has already helped me.
I have now implemented it like this: https://hastebin.com/rekoliqufi.py

That's how it works, but the second loop can still write more efficiently or? That is actually the same loop only I execute something else. What still confuses me is the else in the first loop. This should only be executed if no old channels are found. But it finds channels and still writes "No old channels found" at the end. https://i.imgur.com/HfHSIMV.png
Thanks so far, I'm still trying to learn Python and every answer helps.

Comment: I think you're a bit confused about if else statements. Your if is run within the for loop, your else is outside of it. They have zero correlation with each other. You'd typically solve this by having a variable outside the first loop and changing it accordingly to whatever happened within so that you can output the result.